# What kind of issues could come up while upgrading to HTTPS?

Tags: http, https, lamp

We need to upgrade our application from http to https. Our application is built on core php and unaware about exactly what changes required after SSL installed.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP shouldn't be aware.

You tag LAMP suggests you're using Apache - this is what will terminate the SSL and proxy it to your PHP engine which would 'see' the same requests as before.

You may have extra headers available in PHP to indicate that the original request was HTTPS though.